# Moving an image to a random X,Y Coordinates when pressed. Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am developing a app as a project in school and i want an image to change position to a random one when pressed. This is what i have so far,

```
Random rand = new Random();
int nX = rand.nextInt(20);
int nY = rand.nextInt(20);

private Drawable sprite;

public DrawView(Context context, int xRes, int yRes){

    sprite = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.andre8bit);
}

public OnClickListener imageViewListener = new OnClickListener() {

}
```

I have no idea on what to do in the listener.

Comment: in there you have to override the onclick method, generate again a random x,y and set those to the positiion of the image you want to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In there you have to override the **onClick** method, generate again a random x,y and set those to the position of the image you want to move.

## Example:

```
buttonMoveImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            nX = rand.nextInt(20);
            nY = rand.nextInt(20);
            // set the image coordinates...
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need another method to remove the drawn sprite, then draw it again at the new location. So it would be call RemoveDrawn() first then DrawView next. Or in this case you can revert the order, it would be too fast for human to see.

Comment: It was not necessary to create those methods :) worked fine though, Thanks! :)